# Answer check on two series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I want to determine if these two are absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or simply divergent.

1) $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac xn - \frac x{n-1}\right)$$

$$= \frac x2 - \frac x1 + \frac x3 - \frac x2 + \dots + \frac x{n+1} - \frac xn$$
$$=\frac x2 + \frac x{n+1}$$
$$=\frac{x(n+1)+2x}{2n+2}$$
$$=\frac{x(3+n)}{2n+2}$$
$$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x(3+n)}{2n+2} = \frac x2 $$

Hence it diverges $\forall x \ne 0$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left|\frac xn - \frac x{n-1}\right|$$
$$=\int_{2}^\infty \frac{|x|}{n^2 - n} dn$$
$$= \dots$$ Still working on it

2) $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left|\frac1{(\log n)^2} \right| \gt \left|\frac 1n \right|$$ Since $|\frac 1n |$ diverges as harmonic series, our series diverges.

Comment: You can not distribute the $\sum_n$ in the first series. You can sum it using [telescoping technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: Overall, your notation is incorrect in both examples. I have some idea of what you mean, but it is not what you have written.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal But the series of a sum is the sum of the series?

Comment: The term is "diverges" not "diverges absolutely."

Comment: @user151558 Only if the series separately converge, these do not.

Comment: @Process91 Oh I see, that makes sense

Comment: @user151558 You actually arrived at the correct closed form expression for the partial sums, but what you have written prior to that is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (1): Don't split it up like that, the two series (independently) diverge (as you mentioned, they are harmonic). Instead, use the grouping of terms given to your advantage. Write a closed form expression for the partial sum (hint: telescoping). To determine absolute convergence, first combine the expression:
$$\left | \frac x n - \frac x {n-1} \right| = \frac{?}{n(n-1)}.$$
Now the question is does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ converge?

Finally, to address uniform convergence, what tests do you know? Specifically, I'm thinking of the [Weierstrass M-Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassM-Test.html), which could be used to show that the convergence is uniform on a compact set (i.e. a closed and bounded interval). The convergence is not uniform in general, however. (Why?)

For (2): Here the terms of the series are already positive, so conditional and absolute convergence are the same thing. Comparison test is the right idea, what you have written is false. You mean to write
$$\frac{1}{\log^2(n)}>\frac 1 n$$
for large enough $n$, and since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n$ diverges, by the comparison test $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {\log^2(n)}$ diverges.

Comment: Woops I wrote that one(2) down right, and typed it up wrong, and just wrote the conclusion then.

Comment: Oh the past exam question says afterwards: "For the series in part (a)(here 1)) above, is the convergence uniform in $x$".

That is why I wrote that in there

Comment: OK, then we can address that also.

Comment: So the closed form here is $|\frac{-x}{n^2 - n}|$ (for absolute convergence I mean)

Comment: @user151558 The "closed form" was for the conditional convergence. Yes, we find:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac x n - \frac x {n-1} \right| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x|}{n(n-1)},$$
Now does this converge or diverge? (One test that would work would be the comparison test. The integral test also would work.)

Comment: (That should have started at $n=2$)